# WAMP Intranet - Forbidden for port 80 only

Tags: wamp, wampserver, intranet

I setup wamp to be accessible on an intranet.

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

But when I try to access it I get 401 Forbidden.
On the machine itself there is no problem (localhost), only other computers on the intranet.

When I changed the wamp access to use port 8080, it's all working great but I need it on port 80.

No skype or other programs are installed, and as I said port 80 is working within the localhost.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using please?

Answer (score 0):

If its **WAMPServer 3 you are using** then there is a default Virtual Host setup for `localhost` and that is where you should make the accesibility changes

Edit `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf`

In there you should find this :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Add your intranet access into here like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it is version 3. Is Vhost is the only option?

Comment: The VHost is ALREADY SETUP BY DEFAULT, you just need to edit it. And because it is setup, the config in the `httpd.conf` is ignored

Answer (score 0):

edit httpd-vhosts.config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

change **Require local** to **Require all granted**.
when it is Require local it can be accessed only through localhost request from other hosts are denied.
Finally it looks like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```